# Overriding a CSS value in a WordPress website

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor

Been creating a website recently with Elementor.

I have a line of code in the source code of the website saying

```
img 
{
    height:auto;
}
```

Is there any way to add custom `css` to the website to ignore this line of code and somehow override it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, via the customizer in *WordPress* you can.

Navigate inside the `wp-admin` to:

```
display -> customizer -> extra CSS
```

Then inside the `textarea` just put

```
img 
{
    height: 200px; // whatever you wanna overwrite it with
}
```

Don't forget to click *publish*!

---

Or if you have access to the theme editor, you can edit the `CSS` file there, you can find it under

```
wp-admin -> display -> Theme editor
```

Then try to locate the *source file* where that line of code has been defined.

You can locate the source file by looking in your `element inspector` using any browser. It will show you which file has that line of code and on which line you can find it.

Answer (score 1):

Following @Red instructions for adding extra CSS on Wordpress, you can also override it by using `!important`, you can use it everywhere, also before the first declared css as i made in this snippet.

```css
img {
  height:50px !important;
}

img {
  height:auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <img src="https://www.adslzone.net/app/uploads/2019/04/borrar-fondo-imagen.jpg">
</html>
```

Without `!important` you need to collocate your new css after the one you want to override.

```
img {
  height:auto;
}

img {
  height:50px;
}
```